# Building Lineage os : Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible

Tags: lineageos, builds

I am trying to build Lineage OS for the A52 4G, I'm at the building step, and then the compiler exits because "Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible".

[Kernel](https://github.com/Simon1511/android_kernel_samsung_sm7125)

[Device tree](https://github.com/Simon1511/android_device_samsung_a52q)

[Second one which is required by the first one](https://github.com/Simon1511/android_device_samsung_sm7125-common)

[Vendor files](https://github.com/Simon1511/android_vendor_samsung_sm7125-common)

How can I fix this ?
The full error log:

````
For ODM SKU = EMPTY_ODM_SKU_PLACEHOLDER, vendor SKU = EMPTY_VENDOR_SKU_PLACEHOLDER
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:241] Cannot parse "out/target/product/a52q/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt" as kernel version, parsing as GKI kernel release.
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:251] Cannot parse "out/target/product/a52q/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt" as GKI kernel release, parsing as kernel release
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:261] Cannot parse "out/target/product/a52q/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt" as kernel release
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:241] Cannot parse "4.14.190-perf" as kernel version, parsing as GKI kernel release.
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:251] Cannot parse "4.14.190-perf" as GKI kernel release, parsing as kernel release
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:278] Successfully parsed content of out/target/product/a52q/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt: 4.14.190-perf
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:58] getFrameworkHalManifest: Reading VINTF information.
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/manifest_android.frameworks.cameraservice.service@2.2.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/manifest_media_c2_software.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/android.system.keystore2-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/android.frameworks.stats@1.0-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/android.system.suspend@1.0-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hidl.allocator@1.0-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/product/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/product/etc/vintf/manifest/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/manifest/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:58] getDeviceHalManifest: Reading VINTF information.
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:79] Sysprop ro.boot.product.vendor.sku=
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/manifest_android.hardware.drm@1.3-service.widevine.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.nfc@1.2-service.samsung.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.cas@1.2-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.qti.hardware.display.allocator-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.neuralnetworks@1.3-service-qti.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.graphics.composer-qti-display.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.usb@1.2-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.health@2.1-samsung.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.graphics.mapper-impl-qti-display.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.wifi.supplicant.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.neuralnetworks@1.3-service-qti-hta.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.lineage.trust@1.0-service.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.vibrator-service.sm7125.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.wifi.hostapd.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.samsung.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@3.0-service.sm7125.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:79] Sysprop ro.boot.product.hardware.sku=
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/odm/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/odm/etc/manifest.xml': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/odm/etc/vintf/manifest/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:64] getDeviceHalManifest: Successfully processed VINTF information
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:64] getFrameworkHalManifest: Successfully processed VINTF information
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:58] getFrameworkCompatibilityMatrix: Reading VINTF information.
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.6.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.4.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.device.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.3.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.5.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/product/etc/vintf/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:64] getFrameworkCompatibilityMatrix: Successfully processed VINTF information
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:58] getDeviceCompatibilityMatrix: Reading VINTF information.
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/vendor/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 VintfObject.cpp:64] getDeviceCompatibilityMatrix: Successfully processed VINTF information
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:112] fetched kernel version 4.14.190
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:116] fetched kernel level from RuntimeInfo ''
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:130] read kernel configs from out/target/product/a52q/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_configs.txt
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.6.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.4.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.device.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.3.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.5.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/product/etc/vintf/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.6.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.4.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.device.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.3.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.5.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/product/etc/vintf/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.6.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.4.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.device.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.3.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.5.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/target/product/a52q/system/system_ext/etc/vintf/manifest.xml': OK
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 HostFileSystem.cpp:54] List 'out/target/product/a52q/product/etc/vintf/': NAME_NOT_FOUND
checkvintf I 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:384] All HALs in device manifest are declared in FCM <= level 5
checkvintf E 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:620] files are incompatible: Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible: HALs incompatible. Matrix level = 5. Manifest level = 5. The following requirements are not met:
checkvintf E 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:620] android.hardware.power:
checkvintf E 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:620]     required: IPower/default (@1-2)
checkvintf E 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:620]     provided:
checkvintf E 04-02 04:47:47 119521 119521 check_vintf.cpp:620] : Success
INCOMPATIBLE```
````

Comment: Sorry, but ROM building is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks, I guess I'll post it on Stack Overflow